# Rscript in Hive

Tags: r, hive

I have a linear regression model created in R. And have the model file stored. How do i run this on a hive table and score inside hive CLI.

This document has some useful information on this. My question is how to code scorer.R wrapper file. What will be the content of the file. Thank

http://www.slideshare.net/huguk/hug-data-science